# APIPlatform (Symfony/REST) - "Error: Bad Request : Invalid IRI\"1\""

Tags: rest, symfony, post, api-platform.com

there is the situation :
I would like to send information to my REST API (**working on Symfony**), but when i tried to send this [line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWw23.png), i got some errors that i don't understand, like : [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8At4.png) .

I really tried to resolve it alone, but nothing helped me on forums.
I think about an attribute than can't probably be set to editiion, or the reverse : an attribute which is not in edition and has to be.

This is what i want : be able to modify "dateCommande" (attribute for Purchase Date) , "statut" (used for see the statement of the purchase) and "idUsager" (used for put an id for a user); and finally be able to create automatically an id ("$id").

Thanks beforehand to help me ! ^^

- Code of my class "Categorie.php" :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\RangeFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotNull;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

/**
 * Commande
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="commande", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_6EEAA67DCF034CDB", columns={"id_usager_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext={"groups"={"commande"},"enable_max_depth"=true},denormalizationContext={"groups"={"commandeecriture"},"enable_max_depth"=true})
 */
class Commande
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Groups({"commande"})
     * @NotNull(message="L'id ne peut être null")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_commande", type="date", nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"commande","commandeecriture"})
     * @NotBlank(message="Date non renseignée")
     */
    private $dateCommande;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="statut", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"commande","commandeecriture"})
     * @NotBlank(message="Statut non renseigné")
     */
    private $statut;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_usager_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @Groups({"commande", "commandeecriture"})
     * @NotNull(message="L'id ne peut être null")
     */
    private $idUsager;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->idArticle = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCommande(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->dateCommande;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $dateCommande
     */
    public function setDateCommande(\DateTime $dateCommande): void
    {
        $this->dateCommande = $dateCommande;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatut(): string
    {
        return $this->statut;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $statut
     */
    public function setStatut(string $statut): void
    {
        $this->statut = $statut;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getIdUsager(): User
    {
        return $this->idUsager;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $idUsager
     */
    public function setIdUsager(User $idUsager): void
    {
        $this->idUsager = $idUsager;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please copy past the error here, instead of using an image

Answer (score 0):

api-platform uses IRI instead of entity ids, try to replace `idUsager="1"` by `idUsager="/usager/1"`. I'm guessing `usager` is the name of the related entity but if it's not then you just need to replace the actual name in the snippet in general it must be `/related-entity-name/id`

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your answer and sorry for the missing.
There is the Error than i get when i try to execute `idUsager="/usager/1"` :               ```{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
  "title": "An error occurred",
  "detail": "Syntax error",
  "trace": [
    {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "/home/flav/Documents/ArchitectureDistribuesWebService/Symfony5WSClient/vendor/symfony/serializer/Encoder/JsonDecode.php",
      "line": 92,
      "args": []
    }...```

Comment: @Butter that does not tell enough, I can only see that there is a syntax error, but i can't see your code

Comment: Sorry, yes... There is what i put on the area "post method, just to remember it : i just have the error on 2 entity, specifically on "POST" section, no PUT or GET for example ;)) :

{
  "dateCommande": "2022-07-23T14:02:20.513Z",
  "statut": "occupé",
  "idUsager" : "\usager\1"
}

Comment: There is an error in `\usager\1`, it should be `/usager/1`, use slashes not backslashes